# Script a list of users who have been logged in for more than 24 hours?

Tags: linux, bash, login

I am attempting to create a simple script that will produce a simple list of users who are logged into a system for longer than 24 hours.

I've seen the `w` command is good for being able to view idle time, but how can I make a list of users whom have been on the system idle for 24 hours?

Here is my `w` command output

```
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
lisa     tty2                      19:21   57:17   0.03s  0.03s -bash
homer    tty3                      19:22   56:53   0.05s  0.03s -bash
bart     tty1                      19:21   57:25   0.04s  0.03s -bash
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
w --from | awk 'NR < 3 {next;}; $4 ~ "day" {print $1; }' | sort -u
```

Comment: I know little about awk, but when i run this command it list all logged in users and I just created test user today, so i guess my question is where do i manipulate the amount of time?

Comment: @user3347022 Maybe your `w` produces different output from mine. Please add your output (one line for those to be selected and one not to be selected) to your question.

Comment: as it is they should all be selected if they are on longer than 24 hours but they have all been on for only about an hour

Comment: @user3347022 I forgot the quotes. On my system all users have been logged in for more than a day thus I didn't notice the error when testing. And a general hint: You should not accept an answer as long as it doesn't work.

Comment: @user3347022 I had to correct it again: On my systems there are values in the `FROM` column. Your output doesn't have any. Thus the index of the field to be tested must be adapted. It makes sense to use `--from` to get rid of this column completely. Otherwise the `awk` test would fail if there is a value in some lines.

Comment: Ah! I'm working on figuring out awk to fully understand this! But thank you loads! I'm going to study this command to better get an idea of awk. From what I can tell it's pretty powerful.